# Edit first commit of git repository not working as expected

Tags: git

I have a pretty simple git repository that I've created for a training. It has a master branch containing just the initial commit, and several branches that root from master. The point is that I want to edit the initial commit (pointed by master) to add a readme file with some instructions, but after doing that, instead of editing that very first commit, it seems that a new commit is created and master branch is updated to point to it. I've tried different strategies to do it: amending that first commit and rebasing interactively with `--root` option, but all of them result in the same outcome.

This is my git log:

```
* e2c1de0 (origin/rerere-base, rerere-base) Add second line to 
rerere/file.txt to provoke a conflict
* 58af1bf Add file.txt for rerere example
...
| * 91d8f5b (origin/bisect-run, bisect-run) Add new test for minus
| * c7db602 Intentionally add a failing commit
...
| * 4ffaae9 Add calculator class with sum method
| * 188e648 Create package skeleton
|/
* 1d44a36 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Initial commit
```

And this is what results after editing the first commit:

```
* 60f5e5c (HEAD -> master) Initial commit
* e2c1de0 (origin/rerere-base) Add second line to rerere/file.txt to provoke a conflict
* 58af1bf Add file.txt for rerere example
...
| * 91d8f5b (origin/bisect-run) Add new test for minus
| * c7db602 Intentionally add a failing commit
...
| * 4ffaae9 Add calculator class with sum method
| * 188e648 Create package skeleton
|/
* 1d44a36 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Initial commit
```

Note that a new commit has been added with message `Initial commit`, and its parent is `e2c1de0 (origin/rerere-base)` not the original initial commit. 
Really weird, isn't it?

Could someone explain me what's happening and ideally provide a solution?

The original aforementioned repository is located at https://github.com/beni0888/gitlikeapro just in case someone would like to try it by themselves.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've been able to understand what's happening here thanks to @torek's answer. The issue implies two things:

- I know that ammending or editing a previous commit with rebase implies to rewrite the history and generates a new commit. However, I thought that dependant commits (eg. those that have it as ancestor) were properly updated, which I'm afraid is not like that.
- I was using git log with `--oneline` option to check the history, and that was misleading me, as I thought that the newly generated commit was not a root commit and was a child of the previous one in history, which is not true, and you can check it if you show the history without `--oneline` option.

See the difference below:

```
* commit 60f5e5c474719f2a6557859b04154c1b7a4d9e4b (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
  Author: ...
  ...
* commit e2c1de0a44be64e187a16a4e6bb380caef2343b7 (origin/rerere-base)
| Author: ...
| ...  
* commit 58af1bfce7a5a27143a3ca5dff464e004306c7f5
| Author: ...
| ...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.  *Any* attempt to change a commit actually produces a new commit.

It's physically impossible<sup>1</sup> to change a commit, because the commit's hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of the commit's contents.  If you make a new commit with different contents, this is a different commit with a different hash ID.

That is how `git rebase` works: it takes a whole chain of existing commits and makes new, improved, *different* commits from them.  The *branch name*, which used to locate the last of the old dull commits, is then rewritten to point to the last of the shiny new commits.  Anyone who is not aware of the old commits' hash IDs, and simply uses the *name* to access the commits, sees the new commits: and it seems as though they changed.

Anyone who still has the original commits' hash IDs, however, sees the *old* commits under the old IDs, because they are still in the repository.

To get everyone to use the new commits, you must rewrite *all* the names, after copying *all* the commits to new commits, for every commit "after" (descendant-from) the one you attempted to change, but actually copied.  This is because each subsequent commit contains the hash ID of its parent, so you need to copy the child to a new commit that has a new and different parent, then copy the child's child to renumber *its* parent, and so on.

Note that `git log --graph` *without* `--oneline` will show you that the new commit is a root commit.  With `--oneline` it is hard to tell that this is the case, since the ASCII graph drawing just has the two `*` characters in the same column:

```
* <hash> new root commit
* <hash> tip of other branch
```

If there were more text lines, you would see the difference between:

```
* <hash> tip of some branch
|        that uses more than one
|        line in the output
|
* <hash> another commit
```

and:

```
* <hash> new root commit
         with more than one line

* <hash> tip of some branch
...
```

Other graphical viewers (gitk, git-gui, etc) draw better graph lines and make this clearer, but it's rare to come upon multiple roots like this.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, not *quite* impossible: if you find a hash collision (see https://shattered.it/ for instance) you could make two different commits that have a single hash ID.  However, due to Git's internal setup, you can't *replace* the old object if your new object has the same hash ID, so it remains impossible to *change* the commit even in this case.  What you could do is carefully construct two separate repositories, one having one commit with the colliding ID, and the other having the other different commit with that same ID.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I totally understand that ammending a commit implies creating a new commit and rewriting the history. However, I thought that every commit depending on it (in this case those that have it as their parent) would be property updated, but it seems that's not the case. Git log with oneline was misleading me, as I thought the newly created commit was not a root one, but a child of the previous one in the graph. Now I see the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

> I want to edit the initial commit (pointed by master) to add a readme file with some instructions

Add the new file as a fresh commit.

If you need it in multiple branches, merge or cherry-pick.

---

#### Amending public commits - just don't do it.

[Git doco](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---amend) states:

> **--amend** (...)
>   You should understand the implications of rewriting history if you amend a commit that has already been published. (See the "RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section in git-rebase.)

[RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) states

> Rebasing (or any other form of rewriting) a branch that others have based work on is a bad idea: anyone downstream of it is forced to manually fix their history.

If in doubt, you here is another message [a tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history) :

> **Don’t amend public commits**
>
> Amended commits are actually entirely new commits and the previous commit will no longer be on your current branch. This has the same consequences as resetting a public snapshot. Avoid amending a commit that other developers have based their work on. This is a confusing situation for developers to be in and it’s complicated to recover from.